# Concat thymelief string and var

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I need concat this

```
<form id="'reportingForm' + ${report.suffixe}".....
```

But is nor working

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Everything in thymeleaf works inside th: attributes

```
<form th:attr="id='reportingForm' + ${report.suffixe}" ...
```